# What is this plant on the photos?

Tags: botany, species-identification, flowers

Found in Kustaankartano, Helsinki, Finland in June 2015.

(for closeup view, copy image URL and open in new window and then zoom in)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: could we get some close up pictures of the flower? I'd suggest it may be some kind of clematis (is it a climbing plant?)

Comment: @rg255 I don't have them from another angle, unfortunately, however you can copy the image URL, open it in a new window and watch the photo much closer than SE shows.

Comment: @rg255 what about climbing, I've added one additional photo to the question, please check it out. It seems to be that it's climbing on a metallic netted fence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is one of the many species and hybrids of [Clematis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clematis) that is grown in gardens. It looks similar to the common [*Clematis alpina*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clematis_alpina) but might be a closely related species or à hybrid.

[image]
(Picture of C. alpina fr.o.m. Wikipedia)

Comment: Would have been my guess too. Those stems look pretty diagnostic. Do you find that quite often the answer to the question "what's that interesting blue-flowered vine?" is Clematis? :)

Comment: @Oreotrephes Hehe, yeah, it's often a good bet, at least in European gardens.